# How to I combine data from two XML files into the same structure?

Tags: xml, merge

I have two XML files that I'd like to merge the data into the same structure as the example below. The actual files are larger and more complex so copying and pasting is not an efficient option.

Is there any way that this can be done quickly?

File1.xml:

```
<part1>
<g1> abc. 
</g1></part1>
<part2>
<g2> def.
</g2></part2>
```

File2.xml:

```
<part1>
<g1> 123.
</g1></part1>
<part2>
<g2> 456.
</g2></part2>
```

Combined.xml

```
<part1>
<g1> abc. 123.
</g1></part1>
<part2>
<g2> def. 456.
</g2></part2>
```

Comment: Using what platform/language?  XSLT?  .NET? Java? Something else?  Also, none of your sample XML is valid as a single document - they all have multiple root nodes.  Is this actually the case, or did you change something from your actual inputs?

Comment: Oh, I made a mistake as I was typing the sample. The actual files are bible databases stored in XML format. I'd like to combine two different languages into one XML file.

Comment: You've not answered the first part @DanField's question.  Is that because you're looking for a tool to perform the merger rather than writing code?  You will not find a tool that would not require programming-like configuration to specify how exactly the merger should take place.

Comment: Right, but what tool or language do you plan to use to combine them?  If you're looking for a recommendation for one that's considered off topic here.  Research XSLT, or some other pgoramming language that you're already familiar with.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there's loads of ways to 'merge' XML. But what you're going to need to do it is an XML parser, because XML is a structured data format.

Which one you use is very much a question of which language do you prefer?

Me? I like Perl and `XML::Twig`:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Twig;
use Data::Dumper;

my $snippet1 = '<root><part1>
<g1> abc. 
</g1></part1>
<part2>
<g2> def.
</g2></part2></root>';

my $snippet2 = '<root><part1>
<g1> 123.
</g1></part1>
<part2>
<g2> 456.
</g2></part2></root>';


my $first = XML::Twig->new()->parse($snippet1);

sub merge {
    my ( $twig, $element ) = @_;
    return unless $element->tag =~ m/^g/;
    my $cur   = $element;
    my $xpath = '';
    while ( $cur->parent ) {
        $xpath = $cur->tag . "/" . $xpath;
        $cur   = $cur->parent;
    }

    # print "/",$xpath,"\n";

    if ( my $other = $first->get_xpath( $xpath, 0 ) ) {
        if (    $element->text_only
            and $other->text_only )
        {
            $element->set_text(
                ( $other->text_only . " " . $element->text_only ) =~ s/\n//rg );
        }
    }
}

my $combined = XML::Twig->new(
    pretty_print  => 'indented_a',
    twig_handlers => { '_all_' => \&merge }
)->parse($snippet2)->print;
```

This'll take your source text and turn it into:

```
<root>
  <part1>
    <g1> abc.   123.</g1>
  </part1>
  <part2>
    <g2> def.  456.</g2>
  </part2>
</root>
```

But I'm sure there's better routes you can take, and other languages you can use.